# how to parse a tables from internet source and use it in android application

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, html-parsing

I am a new in Android and Java coding but I want to learn :)

I have a question but I can't find a solve.. and I'll be very grateful if someone can help me.

On internet source I get tables like this

```
<table class="class1" cellspacing="1" border="0">
<tr class="IEDummyRow">
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Heading">
    <td colspan="4">St ab</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ColHeaders">
    <td class="RouteCol">A</td><td>1st</td><td>2nd</td><td>3rd</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">zxczxc</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="OddRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">ewrewr</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">jgjhfh</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="OddRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">bvnvnv</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">tryrty</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
```

```
<table class="class2" cellspacing="1" border="0">
<tr class="IEDummyRow">
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Heading">
    <td colspan="4">St cd</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ColHeaders">
    <td class="RouteCol">B</td><td>1st</td><td>2nd</td><td>3rd</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">jhlhjkl</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="OddRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">ouioiuo</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">bmbvmbv</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="OddRow">
    <td class="RouteCol">bfgbccb</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td><td>00:00</td>
</tr>
```

- number of rows in each tables can be different depends from answer from server

I don't understand how get information from parsing and use it in android application.
- using array or using sql

In application I want to recive the same tables..

Thank you

Comment: why are you going hard, just use JSON or sqlite for getting data from the web service.